# Is my PostgreSQL query still running even if server closed the connection?

Tags: postgresql

Postgres noob here. I have a very long `postgresql` query running an update on about ~3 million rows. I did this via `psql` and after about the second hour I got this message:

```
server closed the connection unexpectedly
    This probably means the server terminated abnormally
    before or while processing the request.
The connection to the server was lost. Attempting reset: Succeeded.
```

Is my query still running? I did run:

```
select *
from pg_stat_activity
where datname = 'mydb';
```

and I do still see a row with my update query, with the `state = active`, `wait_event_type = IO`, and `wait_event = DataFileRead`. Do I need to be worried that my connection closed out? Is my query still running, and is the best way to check for done-ness to keep checking up with

```
select *
from pg_stat_activity
where datname = 'mydb';
```

?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your query will not succeed. Your client lost its connection, and while the backend server process that was handling your UPDATE is still going, it will notice that the client disconnected when it tries to return the query status upon completion, and abort the transaction (whether or not you had performed a BEGIN; every statement in PG is implicitly in a transaction even without BEGIN/COMMIT). You will need to re-issue the UPDATE.

Comment: and how does someone makes its so that if connection is lost - query will still succeed?